# How to convert a Json tree of string keys and float values to a Map

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the below String and I wanted to convert it into a `Map` of `String`, `Float`.

I was able to parse it into a `JsonNode`. Is there a way to directly convert it into a `HashMap`?

```
private ObjectMapper json = new ObjectMapper();
String tree = "{\"string1\": 0.75, \"string2\": 0.85}";
JsonNode root = json.readTree(tree);
```

How do I convert the root into a `Map<String,Float>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Map<String, Float> map = mapper.readValue(tree, new TypeReference<Map<String, Float>>(){});
```

Comment: I get a compile error ""TypeReference is abstract and cannot be initiated

Comment: Did you put the empty curly brackets?

Comment: when I add the curly brackets I get "Cannot resolve method 'readValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode, anonymous org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Float>>)'"